# Making Two Lists Identical

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4, flash-builder, mxml

I have a list (mx:List) in the master class of my Flex project.

I have another class that handles something else, but needs to have this identical list in it, all the functions of the list and the copy of the list needs to be able to do exactly the same things to the master class as the master class' own list (such as the on click action and the change action).

Is there an easy way to just reference the master class' list and tell my dialog class to just show the list from the master class?

So far I tried recreating the list and all its functions, but this is proving difficult because of just how intertwined the master class list is with itself. I also tried a simplistic approach and just setting the list equal to the master class list by using FlexGlobals, but that didn't work.

Comment: Make your list into a reusable component. You're going to need to break apart the list and its code from your main class. Then use this component in the main class and elsewhere. Use the same ArrayCollection as the data provider to the list component.

Comment: that's going to be incredibly challenging. This list is a huge portion of this thing. Basically I used to have a separate selector for screens and layers, but now I have to combine them. Screens are their own class, along with a skin and I need the get the list of layers into the list of screens (with the layers under their proper screens). Originally you'd pick a screen from a separate menu and the layers would pop up. Now it's more of a drop down, but combining the once separate aspects is proving incredibly difficult.

Comment: Do you need the list object or will just the data provider due?

Comment: I figured that was the case. Aside from sharing the same dataProvider, there are no simple shortcuts. A `DisplayObject` can only have one parent. So you can't get a reference to the list and add it to the stage somewhere else. It is likely the time you spend in refactoring will be worth it in the long run :)

Comment: basically what has to be the same is the data and the click events, and the master class needs to know what the dialog's list is currently selected. Right now the plan is to bring in the arraycollection of data from the master class into the dialog. This I did already. Then it's getting the click events and selections working, still having problems with those